# How to start Direct Call in Samsung?

Tags: android, android-intent, galaxy, samsung-mobile, telephonymanager

Samsung's smartphones has one nice feature called [direct call](http://www.samsung.com/global/galaxys3/directcall.html) - i.e. while messaging one can just lift telephone to ears and it starts calling.

This kind of function implemented in SGS-3, SGS-4 Note-1 and Note-2.

I'm writing messaging application and just thinking how to use this feature.

So the question is: how to start direct call from Android app? I understand that it's non-standard function but probably there's some kind of API or Intent which allows to use direct call on Samsungs?

Any clues/hints/ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess it is function using calling plus light sensor, which has bunch of examples around.

***Updated***

Sorry, it would be **Proximity Sensor**. just try putting on your hand when messaging, whether it calls or not.
Here is the link for it.
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_position.html#sensors-pos-prox

Comment: if Samsung is wise, they might mixed it with gyro sensor too I guess. ex) when messaging, if phone moves up and object get closed, then call

Comment: Great answer: in the end I think detection is a mixture of 3 sensors:

1) Light sensor
2) Proximity sensor
3) Gyro sensor

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that there is some special API for this. I believe it's just a functionality of messanging app. It combines two features:

**A. Calling a phone**

It does something like that:

```
Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:1234567890"));
startActivity(callIntent);
```

**B. Motion sensors usage**

You can take a look how to use [it](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_motion.html) here. It detect that phone goes up for some period of time (may be it also measure rotation to see that it's correct gesture).

Comment: I think it uses the proximity sensor to detect if you have your phone near something ( in this case your head).

Comment: @StephaneMathis: It could be. However, I think they use some mix. If it was just the proximity sensor, there would be too many accidental calls.

Answer (score -3):

To use the **DIRECT CALL FEATURE** on the **SAMSUNG GALAXY NOTE II** simply do this:

During a **TEXT MESSAGE** that you are having with another person just simply put your **GALAXY NOTE II** up to your ear and then it will **automatically dial** & call the person that you are currently having a **TEXT MESSAGE CONVERSATION WITH**

Comment: barmaley is looking for a way to do this programmatically.